# Call Node/Express function from a GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: express, github-actions

I have an Express server that is running with a specific caching system using node-cache.
I would like to be able to clear this cache by using a GitHub Actions workflow.

I can't see what the best option is.

Could someone give me their opinion on that?

Comment: make an endpoint, then touch it from the github action with curl etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for the answer. What would you suggest to restrict the endpoint to be used only by my GitHub Action and unauthorized for everyone else?

Comment: Require some kind of authentication, e.g. a token that's provided to the action as a secret?